# Log transforming an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, simulation

I'm doing some numerical simulations of an exponential growth like system which, for simplicity, has the form:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}= ax + bxy \quad\quad \frac{dy}{dt}= cy + dxy 
$$

For some parameter values i get instability in the simulation though I remember reading a paper which used log transformations to prevent this. Any ideas on how I could do this or how to rewrite the equations as:

$$
\frac{d log(x)}{dt}= \ldots \quad\quad \frac{d log(y)}{dt}= \ldots
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(If you need more information, for example Lyapunov functions, this equation is similar to [Lotka-Volterra equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations).)

Dividing the first equality by $x$:
$$\frac{1}{x} \frac{dx}{dt}=a+by$$
i.e:
$$\frac{d \log(x)}{dt}=a+by$$
and similarly:
$$\frac{d \log(y)}{dt}=c+bx$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you go from $\frac{1}{x} \frac{dx}{dt}$ to $\frac{d log(x)}{dt}$?

Comment: @Tom It can also be written as: $\frac{d}{dt} \log(x(t)) = \frac{1}{x(t)}x'(t)$